# Flask-Restless API Endpoints only work sometimes

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, flask-restless

I am building a Webservices API using Flask-Restless, Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLite3. I have a class called Place, which also is a table containing different places around my city. From what I understand I should be able to post new data at endpoints like so:

```
http://localhost:5000/webservices/api/place
```

I also should be able to see a json response of everything in that table when I navigate to that url in a browser. This only works part of the time... some times I am able to see the json response, and other times I get a 404 url not found error. I keep refreshing the page and eventually the json response comes back. I still am not able to post the api endpoint without getting a 404 (or a 500 occasionally?).... am I doing something wrong?

I am posting like this:

```
>>> import json  
>>> import requests  .
>>> newplace = {'name': u'Carls Jr.', 'address': '123 Main Street'}
>>> r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/webservices/api/place', data=json.dumps(newplace),
...                   headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
>>> r.status_code, r.headers['content-type']
(404, 'text/html')
```

Here's my code:

```
import flask
import flask.ext.sqlalchemy
import flask.ext.restless

# Create the Flask application and the Flask-SQLAlchemy object.
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)

#place 
class Place(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True)
    address = db.Column(db.Unicode)


# Create the database tables.
db.create_all()

# Create the Flask-Restless API manager.
manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)

manager.create_api(Place, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])

# start the flask loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Are you sure about de 'webservices' part of the URL you use : http://localhost:5000/webservices/api/place . Just to be really certain, you can use manager.create_api(Place, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'], collection_name='place', url_prefix='/webservices/api')